# What operating systems are supported by Substrate?

Tags: substrate

I've completed the following tutorial on an Ubuntu server...
https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/create-your-first-substrate-chain/setup

I then tried it on a Red Hat distro (CentOS (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)) but it failed to compile.

Prompted me to ask what OS's are supported by Substrate?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: "but it failed to compile." **with what error?**

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. What have you tried? What have you got? Please ensure you include the [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

- [The Getting Started guide lists macOS (BSD), Ubuntu/Debiant, and Arch Linux](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/knowledgebase/getting-started/) as preferred distributions. It also says Windows is supported, though not preferred (due to Windows lacking a Bash-style shell by default).
- That doesn't mean other distros won't work - if "it failed to compile" then your machine is missing some dependency. The platform is built using Rust (for the service) and JS+npm for the front-end GUI - so it follows that Substrate *should* run on any platform that Rust (and npm) will run on (i.e. *every* modern distro of Linux).